# Count array values in multidimensional array based on a different value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to count values of an array based on a different value in the array.

Here is an example, with the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => 53
            [grade] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => 40
            [grade] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user] => 53
            [grade] => A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user] => 53
            [grade] => B
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [user] => 53
            [grade] => C
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [user] => 52
            [grade] => A
        )
)
```

I need a way to count all of a specific grade for a specific user.

My first thought was `array_count_values()`, which would only work to get me the total amount of a specific grade, not based on the user. Other than that idea, I haven't been able to think of any more, and am having difficulty finding good search terms for such a thing to try to find a solution.

I need a way to say "User X has Y amount of grade Z" (User **53** has **2** grade **A**)

How can I extract the information I need from the array?

Comment: How about old plain `foreach` iteration?

Comment: Hint: `foreach ($grades as $i) $grouped[$i['user']][] = $i['grade'];` Take it from here…

Comment: @u_mulder That would almost work but I'm using the results to build a chart in chart.js which needs all of the grades for each user in it's own array, so just using a regular foreach would mean looping through all of the users multiple times

Comment: @deceze This looks like a pretty good way to handle this, the current solution on the question would require me to loop through all my users multiple times, but yours would be just once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
// Function that take you array, the id_user you want and the grade you want
function getGradeByUser ($array, $id_user, $grade) {
    $count = 0;

   // Just count how many time you get the grade for the specific user
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if ($data['user'] == $id_user && $data['grade'] == $grade) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    // Write down the result
    echo "User " . $id_user. " has " . $count . " grade " . $grade;
}
```

With your array and your example, just do :

```
getGradeByUser ($array, 53, "A");
```

The output is :

```
User 53 has 2 grade A
```

---

EDIT : Now if you want all information, just do :

```
// Result array
$result = array();

// I will add and count all grade by user
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if (!isset($result[$data['user']][$data['grade']])) {
        $result[$data['user']][$data['grade']] = 1;
    } else {
        $result[$data['user']][$data['grade']]++;
    }
}

// I just loop through my result array and display the information
foreach ($result as $user => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $grade => $count) {
        echo "User " . $user. " has " . $count . " grade " . $grade . "<br>";

    }
}
```

The output is :

```
User 53 has 2 grade A
User 53 has 1 grade B
User 53 has 1 grade C
User 40 has 1 grade A
User 52 has 1 grade A
```

Comment: This would _work_, but I was trying to avoid a lot of foreach processing (I probably should have mentioned this in my question) because I feel like it could slow down my application. There could be dozens of users, with many of each grade. This solution would mean looping through all of my users 4 times each. That's why I mentioned `array_count_values()`, because it avoids using loops.

Comment: The first solution with the function is just one loop through your array :) So you want more a solution with the less foreach possible to display all data at once?

Comment: No, I'm not actually trying to display any data. I put that in my question to try to explain what I'm actually trying to get from the array, I don't need that as an output. I also don't really need it all at once. I'm using the data to display a chart in my application. Chart.js requires all the data in separate datasets, this means for each user I need a dataset that holds each grade separately. For example, for the Grade A dataset, I would need an array like `[2,1,1]` (given my code above). The reason your solution would need multiple loops, is because there are multiple grades I need.

Comment: If you are looking in term of performance, maybe take a look at this : http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/, doing a foreach is not that slow, your array is small and not very deep so it shouldn't be a problem. But try other solution if you can check what is faster, I'm curious too !

Comment: Yes the array in my example is pretty small, but in production this array could have dozens of users with any number of each of the 4 possible grades.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid a lot of looping for my solution because my production data could potentially have dozens of users with any number of grades for each of them.

This is what I came up with:

Loop through all my results once, and sort them into arrays where the key is the userid and the contents is a count of each of the grades for that user (Sort of like deceze mentioned in a comment)

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($results as $result) {
    $grouped[$result['user']][$result['grade']]++;
}
```

Now I can access each users counts for any number by doing this: `$grouped[USERID][GRADE]`, so I just throw all that information into the correct format for my needed application:

```
$records['datasets'] = [
    ["label" => "A", "backgroundColor" => "#77ef77", "data" => []],
    ["label" => "B", "backgroundColor" => "#84c584", "data" => []],
    ["label" => "C", "backgroundColor" => "#f9f96d", "data" => []],
    ["label" => "TECH", "backgroundColor" => "#d68d8d", "data" => []]
];

foreach($records['labels'] as $record) {
    $records['datasets'][0]['data'][] = $grouped[$record['uid']]['A'] ?: 0;
    $records['datasets'][1]['data'][] = $grouped[$record['uid']]['B'] ?: 0;
    $records['datasets'][2]['data'][] = $grouped[$record['uid']]['C'] ?: 0;
    $records['datasets'][3]['data'][] = $grouped[$record['uid']]['TECH'] ?: 0;
}
```